# "Signal out of range" when booting the PC from the CDROM

Tags: windows-8, boot, display, compact-disc

I changed the configuration on my Windows 8 PC so it boot from de CDROM. Then I insert the DVD with the Ubuntu ISO and reboot. I saw something like "Booting from CD/DVD..." on the screen but it's very fast, and then, my monitor says "Signal out of range". This only happen when booting from the CDROM, working with Windows 8 works well, also on the setup.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that the CD was broken, or at least the data inside. I solved this by using a pendrive instead, copying the ISO from my PC to there with [this tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:
It means the software on the CD is cause your video card to produce a resolution at a refresh rate not supported by your monitor.

If you could somehow lower the request to say 800 x 600 with 60hz it should work. However, we have no idea what monitor you have so I can only guess what its supported settings are.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this page](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/674), if you press `F4` when you get the "Booting from CD/DVD" message, do you see a "Safe Graphics Mode" option?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. If I press F4 (very quickly because the message appears only for some miliseconds) then it shows me "Booting from CD/DVD..." and it stays there, nothing happens, and I can't touch nothing (also, there's no "Safe Graphics Mode" option). The DVD with the Ubuntu ISO is inside the CDROM. If I do not press F4 then the "Signal out of range" message appears. Note that this message is showed by the monitor, not by the PC itself. No I guess the machine is showing something that mi monitor can't interpretate. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about this specific message, but I would first check that you don't have UEFI's secure boot on (turn it off if it is on), and also that (if you do have EFI) you are not trying to use a 32 bit DVD, which will not work. I have not even gotten a 32-bit version of GRUB i compiled to boot on a computer with 32-bit EFI.

What I hear you saying is that the Windows 8 install DVD will not work either. if this is true, try to use something to make a Ubuntu installation USB drive.

Also, make sure your BIOS/UEFI has things like 'fast boot' disabled; some of these optimizations are non-standard and only work with Windows 8.

I have had a lot of experience with wrangling with non-standard hardware and UEFI firmware. I hope you don't have to.

It is also possible your resolution is just too high, in which case I would make a installation USB (since it will be editable) and alter the grub.cfg files in BOOT/ and EFI/, setting them to a resolution manually. put something in like:

GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480x16

GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

This is a extremely low resolution and low-color mode but it should ensure it boots on nearly any system with a 386 CPU or higher (it fits the original VGA specifications). You can alter the settings to suit your particular environment.

You can also make these changes to the ISO but would have to burn another DVD.